# How to remove empty elements from a form in ember, when saving/submitting?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Let's say I have an action in my controller like:

```
actions: {
  save: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.get('model').save().then(function() {
      self.transitionToRoute('surveys');
    }, $.noop);
}
```

The model "hasMany" elements of type "element" (another model, with just a field "title"), that I can access from the controller as:

```
var elements = this.get('elements');
```

I want to remove the elements with empty title before I save. I've tried iterating over the "elements" with forEach and filter, but none of my approaches have worked so far.

Any suggestions? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was residing in the way I was deleting the elements.

Instead of calling destroyRecord() on the elements, the solution is to call removeObject() on the elements array, with the element we want to remove as an option.

Such as:

```
var elements = this.get('elements');

elements.forEach(
  function (element) {
    if(element && ! element.get('title')){
      elements.removeObject(element);
    }
  });
```